# Anchoring to the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to point to a portion in the same page. So used the anchor method. But the problem is, I have a static navigational bar at the top. So the heading of the section goes below the menu bar since the anchor is set to the heading. The menu bar is of `100px` height. I was wondering if there is any way we can show this heading too?

If you want more details, just let me know.

```
<!---NAVIGATION BAR SECTION------>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="features.html">FEATURES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pricing-and-signup.html">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li id="scroll2" class="navLog"><a href="https://my.clickmeter.com">LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li id="scroll3" class="navLog"><a href="pricing-and-signup.html">SIGN UP FREE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!---NAVIGATION BAR ENDS------>
```

This is the nav section from which I wanted to move to other portions

```
 <div class="jumbotron action-block-green ">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="#technology">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#screenshot">SCREENSHOTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#features">FEATURES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I anchored the first link (technology) to here

```
<div class="jumbotron sectionBlock white ">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h2  id="technology" style="color:#202020;margin-top: 0px;">Cutting-Edge Technology</h2>
            <h3>Accurate, Reliable, Scalable and Hi Performace</h3>
            <p style="margin:10px 0">blabhfufwehuf wiuefh wiu hfiuw fiuw fiuwhe fiwu hfiwue fhiwuh f</p>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="certified-uptime"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="multiple-datacenters"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="hosteb-by"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: A fiddle would be better: jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RahulDesai - No, the question should *always* include the relevant code, with a jsFiddle being optional. If jsFiddle were ever to go away or otherwise be inaccessible, then the question loses all value.

Comment: OKay, I will include the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the scrolling using jQuery and changing the anchors in the URL to elements that don't exist on the DOM with the same value for `id` or `name`. (so that the scroll is not done automatically)

[**Living demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/62fzH/1/)

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    //you can see it manually or calculate it using jQuery by using $.height();
    var header = 60; 

    //Getting the anchor and replacing the underscore
    var value =  window.location.hash.replace('_', ''); 

    //getting our destination     
    var dest = $(value).position();

    //if the element exist on the DOM
    if(typeof dest !== "undefined"){
         var dtop = dest.top;

         //proceeding to scroll
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: dtop - header
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

The links in my example look like `#_link1` and the id needed to appear in the DOM should be like `id="link1`:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#_link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#_link2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#_link3">Link 3</a>
</div>
...
<h1 id="link1>Link 1</h1>
```

Of course, you can change the underscore (`_`) on the URL for any other character or symbol you want. Just make sure to replace it for an empty string on the `replace` statement of the code I provided.