# Fixing nav to top, then add margin to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently using this:

```
    $(function(){ // document ready

      var stickyTop = $('.navigation-wrap').offset().top; // returns number 

      $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event  
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
        if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
          $('.navigation-wrap').addClass('sticky');
        }
        else {
          $('.navigation-wrap').removeClass('sticky');
        }
      });

    });
```

And that sticks the navigation to the top of the screen perfectly, however... when using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('navactive');
        });
        $(this).addClass('navactive');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});
```

To highlight the current button depending on how far down the page you have scrolled. The problem is now that the 50px navigation is covering the top of the content. If you click on one of the buttons, the page scrolls down and covers the title.

Is there any way of adding a 50px margin to the code so the nav doesn't get in the way? I did try using offset, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, add more pixels in this line:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
```

For example:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+52
```

You can take a look at [a similar solution I proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888480/anchoring-to-the-same-page/21888756#21888756).

Comment: I had already done that, but I actually added 50, I needed to take it away! I've used:

`top-50`

Which is working for when you click the nav, however it's not working for when you scroll down. I'll have a play!

Comment: You haven't shown us the `onScroll` function so I can not help you with that.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise I hadn't, but I've fixed it using this `var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop()+50;` Thanks for your help.